# g++ custom dynamic library linking error undefined symbol

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, shared-libraries

Ok, I'm looking for a solution for 2 days now. I didn't find anything to solve my problems.

What is currently going on?
So, I tried creating a dynamic library (.so) on Linux Mint Maya 13 with g++.

foolib.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(
    void
    );
```

foolib.cpp:

```
#include "foolib.h"

void foo(
    void
    )
{
   printf ("Hello World!\n");
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "foolib.h"

int main(
    int    argc,
    char** argv
    )
{
    foo ();
};
```

I compiled these files with these instructions:

libfoo.so:

```
g++ -shared -o libfoo.so -fpic foolib.cpp
```

foo:

```
g++ main.cpp -o foo -L -lfoo
```

Creating libfoo.so works without any errors, but foo throws undefined reference ´foo'. I copied sample code from several web pages and tried to compile it, always the same result.

The funny is, I can link do libdl.so (-ldl), load my .so and my function. What am I doing wrong?

I hope I could formulate my question correctly. Please tell me if I didn't. : )

Comment: Shouldn't the command be "g++ main.cpp -o foo -L -llibfoo"?

Comment: what is "nm libfoo.so|fgrep foo" giving?

Comment: can you build executable as "g++ main.cpp -o foo -L$PWD -lfoo -Wl,-rpath=$PWD -Wl,-zdefs -Wl,--fatal-warnings" and tell what happens?

Comment: Please, don't use `#pragma once` (it is obsolete); And learn to pass `-Wall` to `g++` (or to `gcc`). The semicolon after the closing brace of function body is probably wrong. And you might pass `-v` to in your linking command to understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the fast help, it was just the missing "-L./". ^^

Comment: In addition to Basile's comments, idiomatic C++ just says `void foo()` not `void foo(void)`, declaring a parameter list of `void` is an abomination. If your function takes no parameters then declare it with no parameters. The way you've written it with two line-breaks is a hideous abomination and an eyesore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
g++ main.cpp -o foo -L./ -lfoo
```

or

```
g++ main.cpp -o foo libfoo.so
```

Answer (score 2):

You state your foo compilation/link is with `g++ main.cpp -o foo -L -lfoo` and this is where the problem is. The `-L` option requires a parameter that gives the linker an additional directory to search for libraries but you have not provided it. So in your case, the linker thinks `-lfoo` is the name of a directory to search in, not a library to link in.

Change `-L` to `-L.` and it should work.

See [this documentation for more information](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory%20Options).